# Is It Possible To Open An App and Control It At Specific Time?

Tags: android, background, macros, controls, alarmmanager

So I lately have been requested to download an app which I have to press on a button once a day between specific hours. I was wondering if it's possible to build an app which opens the app I downloaded at a specific time, detects when the app is loaded correctly and presses the button automatically each day, without me having enter the app myself and press the button. In addition, will a passcode on my phone block the app from working? And will the phone have to turn on to do it or can it be all done somehow in the background?

If you guys maybe have a tutorial or some video on how to do so I would gladly take any help I can!

Thank you in advance!